# Opencv 3.2.0 python install

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I using python opencv3.2 in ubuntu14.04,install follow [open-python 3.2.0.7 : Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), and installed by pip but still get error when call cv2.imshow()

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583

, so I try build opencv 3.2.0 followed [Install OpenCV 3.0 and Python 2.7+ on Ubuntu](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/),but i didn't see the cv2.so after make install

> CMake: cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

where i can find cv2.so ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like CMake never found your Python dev libararies and/or numpy libraries.
Be sure to `sudo apt install libpython2.7-dev` and `sudo pip install numpy` then specify to CMake where these libraries are using the flags:   
`-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so \
-D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
-D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
The above is for python 2.7 only.

then build and install:

`make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install`

The `cv2.so` file should now reside in your python site-packages or dist-packages folder.

Comment: Hi Kyel, I followed your suggestion, rebuild the opencv, but produce "cv2.cpython-34m.so" in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages after make install, Is there other command for python2.7 in Cmake?

Comment: Is there no similar `.so` file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? Try running `make clean` and then re-run Cmake with the above arguments and build / install again.

Comment: maybe you need to install GTK development libraries to use imshow, if still problem try to install prior to build thw following packages: libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev